# drupal 7 Configuration file location

Tags: drupal, settings, configuration-files, pantheon, drupal-domain-access

I am relocating Drupal 7 website from Pantheon to new hosting and need to configure Domain Access module. But I find some troubles.
Domain Access module gives me the error message:

> Domain module installation is incomplete. See INSTALL.txt and check
>   your settings.php file.
>
> Domain access failed to load during phase: bootstrap include. Please
>   check your settings.php file and site configuration.

So I put the string

> include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc';

to my `/sites/default/settings.php` file. 
But it didn't do any effect. I tried different paths but got no result.
After I've found that my settings.php file have default database settings - not the ones that I've written when installing Drupal site.
So I have deleted setting.php and reinitialize Drupal site from web-browser `*/install.php`. After it I've found newly created `/sites/default/settings.php` with wrong(default data) DB. And `$drupal_hash_salt = '';` But site is working correct.
Additionally, I've changed Permissions to 777 and went to /admin/reports/status and found the row

> Configuration file - Protected

It's very strange.
Can you help me solve this problem and find my Configuration file real location?

Answer (score 1):

Usually Pantheon have different hosting structure from the conventional hosting/self-hosting solutions, first I would check the location of the contrib modules, sometime they are included in sub-directory called contrib, so once the system attempts to load

```
include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc';
```

it will not find it, try to have it like the following might help:

```
include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/contrib/domain/settings.inc';
```

Answer (score 1):

First step is to check if `Domain` module was enabled and get its path  on linux :

```
$ drush pmi --fields=type,project,title,status,path --format=table|sort
```

Other way :

```
$ drush pm-list | grep domain
```

If your module was installed by drush , its path can be `sites/all/modules/contrib/domain/settings.inc` so you have to modify include path like :

```
include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/contrib/domain/settings.inc';
```

Comment: Thank you, but actually I know where is my module files located. But my problem with real settings.php file located. Because I have difficult server configuration (maybe .htaccess or other where rewriting) and Drupal looks not to /sites/default/ but to another dir/file. Do you know where can I check path to Drupal7 Configuration file settings.php ?

Comment: Are you in single site mode or multisite mode ? by default settings.php must be located in sites/default . on fresh install you have an example file default.settings.php